# is JS a gradually typed language?

Tags: programming-languages, javascript, dynamic-typing, static-typing

I was researching on statically typed and dynamically typed concepts and found out there is another type system called gradually typed.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradual_typing)

> Gradual typing is a type system in which variables may be typed either at compile-time (static typing) or at run-time (dynamic typing), allowing software developers to choose either type paradigm as appropriate, from within a single language.
>
> In particular, gradual typing uses a special type named dynamic to represent statically-unknown types and gradual typing replaces the notion of type equality with a new relation called consistency (aka. compatibility) that relates the dynamic type to every other type. The consistency relation is symmetric but not transitive

If I understand those concepts correctly, "Javascript" is a gradually typed language. Am I correct?

Comment: It might help to explain what a gradually typed system is for those of us who don't know. Yes, we can Google it, but it really helps to have pertinent information in your question.

Comment: I can give you a link to a [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradual_typing) page.

Comment: I know. I can find it myself too. I was just suggesting that you put that information in your question. Just like how answers generally should stand on their own, I'd guess questions have the same expectation.

Comment: How do you type a variable at compile-time in JavaScript?

Comment: JavaScript is dynamically typed. TypeScript is a gradually typed JavaScript dialect.

Comment: Ok, this is not about typing through your key board. These are concept for type systems in a programming language. If you explicitly assign a type for a variable in compile time compiler can identify the type and check for errors, That's statically typed behavior. Dynamically typed means, you are not assigning a type for the variable but in run time program will assign a type looking at the value assigned for the variable.

Comment: @CodesInChaos > Thankyou finally a person knows about type system. Anyway if you use "use strict" then it will support for Static types right?

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Why a comment and not an answer? As far as I can tell, what you have written is the answer to the question

Comment: @Roshan.Ind: It's safe to assume that everybody here knows what a type system is. Strict mode does not allow static typing, as you have no way to declare a static type available at compile-time for offline checking. You get slightly more constrained behaviour in a unityped system with runtime type tags, which is still dynamic typing.

Comment: @CodesInChaos> 1st look at the 4th comment. Then I'm sorry I misunderstood the use of use strict and thank you for your answer :)

Comment: BTW: That description on Wikipedia looks pretty horrible. Jeremy Siek's own blog post ["What is Gradual Typing"](http://wphomes.soic.indiana.edu/jsiek/what-is-gradual-typing/) does a much better job.

Comment: @JörgWMittag> Agreed!

Comment: @Carson63000 Declare a UInt32Array or similar. The entries are 32-bit unsigned ints declared at compile time. This is pretty much how asm.js deals with memory... and yes, I know, it's all hinky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mixing static and dynamic typing is still very much an open research issue with several competing approaches, including but not limited to Jeremy Siek's Gradual Typing (which you mentioned), Quasi-Static Typing, Soft Typing, Hybrid Typing (Flanagan), Optional Static Typing (championed for example by Gilad Bracha), Blame Calculus (Wadler and Findler), Coercion Calculus (Henglein), Contracts (Findler and Felleisen), Manifest Contracts (Greenberg, Pierce, and Weirich) and many more.

ECMAScript / JavaScript is *not* gradually typed. It would be stupid to add something that is still an open research problem to a production language such as ECMAScript. A language design committee is *not* the place to do cutting-edge research.

Actually, the ECMAScript committee *tried* to do cutting-edge research by mixing static and dynamic typing in ECMAScript 4 … and that was a spectacular failure.

ECMAScript / JavaScript are dynamically typed. There are no static types, nor is there syntax for type annotations.

Comment: > I think this is the best explained answer. I went through some of the other type systems also. Thank you for sharing those...

Comment: I would say "dynamically weakly typed" or "loosely typed". Just saying "dynamically" is a (undeserved) compliment.

Comment: @Den: Unfortunately, those terms are not well-defined. There are at least a dozen contradictory definitions in the wild. It just doesn't make sense to use those terms.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: In a proper weakly-typed language, variables may be of any type, but the meanings of operators won't change with the types of things upon which it is invoked.  In Apple's HyperTalk language (1990s), the expression `(1 & 2) + 3` would concatenate "1" and "2" as strings, and then add the result as a number to 3, thus yielding 15.  In a strongly-dynamically-typed language like Python, using the "+" operator on two numbers will add then, using it on two strings will concatenate them, and using it on one of each is an error.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: JavaScript's behavior is worse than that of HyperTalk or Python, since it uses the "+" operator for two different purposes, but doesn't cleanly separate the cases where those purposes apply.  This, `12+"X"` yields `"12X"` and `"X"+34` yields `"X34"`, but `12+34` yields 46.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on why JavaScript is not gradually typed, let's look in the other direction at C#, which is statically typed with implicit typing.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx), C# introduced a `var` keyword with version 3.0 released in 2007. It is only allowed on "variables that are declared at method scope", what I would call local variables. The `var` keyword falls short of being a dynamic type, because it allows the compiler to figure out what type the declaration *should*, but then treats all references to that variable as the given type exactly as if you had declared it statically yourself.

Here are some examples of how it can and cannot be used.

```
class MyClass {
    // Standard member variable
    public string MyName = "Patrick";

    // Illegal declaration - var cannot be used here even though the type may be inferred
    // from the literal definition; compiler throws an error
    private var LuckyNumber = 7;
    // Have to do it like this:
    private int LuckyNumber = 7;

    private MyClass(int luckyNumber) {
         LuckyNumber = luckyNumber;
    }

    public MyClass MyClassFactory(int newLucky) {
         // Legal - myInstance is in the method scope
         var myInstance = new MyClass(newLucky);
         // Not legal - myInstance is not a dynamic type just because we declared it with var
         myInstance = new MyOtherClass();

         // We can return myInstance because its type matches the method signature
         return myInstance;
     }
}
```

In other words, C# does not provide a way to declare an variable that can hold an arbitrary type. The closest you can get is with [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29), where assignments are restricted to the inheritance tree.

Note that in sharp contrast, JavaScript would allow the illegal line in `MyClassFactory`. The following is perfectly legal in JS:

```
var foo = "foo";
foo = 1;
foo = 2.0;
foo = new Date();
foo = [];
foo = {};
foo = function() {};
```

Every line changes the type of `foo`. Furthermore, there is no way to declare `foo` as a type that may not be changed.

Note that there are ways to shoehorn static typing into JavaScript, but they are actually wrapper layers around the actual JS code, which ends up every bit as dynamically typed as if you had written it by hand. There are way more ways than I would have imagined, as it turns out: [here is a comprehensive-seeming list of languages (or more properly syntaxes or parsers) that can churn out JavaScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS). Of these, [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) is the most common in my experience.

Finally, a language must provide both dynamic and static declarations in order to be considered dynamically typed. In other words, the following must be possible with some syntax:

```
// Statically typed declaration
Integer myNumber = 3;
// May be legal if the language provides for auto-conversion or dynamic-casting; may
// throw an error. It depends on the language
myNumber = 7.5;

// Static type declaration of an object class
MyParentType instance = new MyParentType();
// legal if MyChildType inherits/extends MyParentType - illegal otherwise
instance = new MyChildType();

// Illegal always - MUST throw an error
instance = new IncompatibleType();

// Dynamic typed declaration
dynamic otherInstance = new MyParentType();
// Legal for variables declared dynamic - MUST NOT throw an error
otherInstance = new IncompatibleType();
```

Note that, as demonstrated, neither C# or JS support *both* types of variable declarations for different reasons.

Comment: "This is commonly referred to as implicit typing, but as the compiler determines the type, I contend that it is therefore gradual typing." This makes no sense unless you change the definition of gradual typing. There is no additional runtime checks involved in type-inferred variables.

Comment: Aw nuts, you're right; I misunderstood. How can I edit it to not make me look stupid...

Comment: I'd just cut the sentence off at "this is commonly referred to as implicit typing." Actually, I believe the proper term is *inferred typing*. Implicit typing redirects to latent typing on wikipedia which is pretty much just dynamic typing.

Comment: @Doval Yep, [it had to go](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/245948/revisions). And you may be right about **inferred** being more broadly correct; but C# is MicroSoft's baby and they call it [implicit typing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx), so they'll just have to keep on being wrong. They're pretty good at that...

Comment: Was not aware MicroSoft adopted that term officially. Good find.

Comment: WOW! this is a very detailed answer, thanx for sharing...

Comment: C# includes a "dynamic" type for variables and other storage locations, which allows for dynamic binding.  Such a type can be useful in cases where the type of something won't be known until run-time, but in cases where the programmer knows what type something should be, it's better for the programmer to let the compiler know as well.